# Расчетный модуль для Excel с чтением настроек из таблицы и выводом результатов

Tags: vba, addons, excel, dll

Есть задача - сделать расчетный модуль для Excel с чтением настроек из таблицы+xml и выводом результатов в таблицу. Варианта я вижу два - `dll + VBA` и `Excel add-in (VSTO)`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой из вариантов проще в установке, обновлении (для десятка пользователей) и может какие узкие места или вообще делать по другому?

Comment: А чем не устраивает xla? В нем же vba + msxml

Comment: В целом подходит, но расчетный модуль не простой и хотелось писать на c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом подошла надстройка Excel уровня приложения (есть шаблон в Visual Studio). Генерится  библиотека и книга excel, книгу можно редактировать отдельно и связь не теряется. Не надо отдельно что-то устанавливать, в первый запуск на компьютере только спрашивается доверяете ли производителю надстройки.
P.S. При масштабировании листа невозможно пользоваться кнопками!